# iterate a certain column to extract its values to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gps, scatter-plot

The 'POLYLINE' column includes all GPS points that a car travels at a certain time (x-axis, y-axis). I need to draw the points in a scatter plot.

The following are some values for POLYLINE column:-
[image]

I want to clean the data first and add two new columns for x-axis and y-axis derived from POLYLINE in order to draw the scatter plot.

Replaced all:-

[image]

The new 'a' column only has numbers in it. So the x-axis labels are the first number, third number, and all the way till the end. Accordingly, the y-axis labels are the second number, fourth number, and all the way till the end.
I am thinking to create a list iterating through the 'a' column to append corresponding values with indexes but it keeps giving me errors.
I have tried many ways but none of them helped. Thank you so much if you could help me solve this problem or give me some ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I'd rearrange the original data as the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    (i, j): {'x': x, 'y': y}
    for i, P in taxi.POLYLINE.iteritems()
    for j, (x, y) in enumerate(P)
}, 'index').rename_axis(['taxi', 'time'])
```

This is just an idea.  Take it if you want it.